# Can headless chrome create PDFs with bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I am creating PDFs using headless chrome, but I have a need to insert bookmarks.  Is there any markup I can add to the html that Chrome would interpret into a PDF bookmark?

Thus far I've tried:

```
<link title="foo" rel="bookmark">Foo</link> <!-- in both the body and head tags -->

<link title="foo" rel="bookmark"/> <!-- empty link tag -->

<a name="foo">Foo</a> <!-- obsolete name attribute -->

<a href="#wrap">Foo</a> <!-- link to a internal id -->

<a href="#wrap" name="foo">Foo</a> <!-- two above combined -->

<a href="#wrap" rel="bookmark">Foo</a> <!-- from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types -->
```

Comment: I suggest searching around for ways to generate PDF bookmarks from HTML / JS / CSS etc. If it's possible, then Puppeteer can do it. Otherwise, it's most likely that Puppeteer won't be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks @KayceBasques, I've found nothing that indicates it's possible.  Might end up being a feature request at this point.

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently possible in Chrome.  See [Chrome Issue 781797](https://crbug.com/781797) and [Skia Issue 7532](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/skia/issues/detail?id=7532) on which it depends.

My current workaround is to use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which generates bookmarks from headings.